# Extract file content with ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

here is a little description of what I am trying to achieve:

I have a text file from which I have to extract data. This data represents basic information about 8 person and for every person, 6 lines of information is used in the text file:

Ex: 
1st line: name, 2nd line: last name, ..... 7th line: name, 8th line: last name, etc...

**After all this information, there is more data formatted in a different way.**

The second part of the data is divided by the character '$'.

I succeeded in extracting all the person's data, but **how do I change the way I extract the second part of the text file's data?** I thought I could change my extracting method where the comment is (see code)

Here's my code to extract the data for the first part:

```
if (inputFile.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            string name, last_name, dob, number, street, city;
            getline(inputFile, name);
            getline(inputFile, last_name);
            getline(inputFile, dob);
            getline(inputFile, number);
            getline(inputFile, street);
            getline(inputFile, city);
            Person p = Person(name, last_name, atoi(dob.c_str()));
            Address a = Address(atoi(number.c_str()), street, city);
            Directory::register(p, a);
        }
        //Code for 2nd part of data should be here no?
} else {
    throw logic_error("File can't be opened");
}
```

Comment: is there a way you know you've moved on from the end of the first section into the second? if so, why not use that as a way to split your operations?

Comment: What isn't working? I don't get it. If the for loop runs fine, then the next getline() will read `$`, so you can just skip that and begin reading the second part of the data the way you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought and I have tried, but it seems like it wont work for an unknown reason. The data in the second part is separated by the character '$'

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using another for loop and ignoring the character for every data set `inputFile.ignore('$', '\n');`

Thanks everyone for the help